# How do I return a value to main from a function called by an argparse function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, argparse

Novice Python student here (running 2.7) trying to out my understanding of functions and argparse...sometimes together.

I have a main function that calls an argparse function, which has an argparse command line argument (-i/--input) that calls a path_check function, which validates the path passed in the input argument. Now I do not how to return the validated input path back to my main function since the path_check function is not called in main. Also wondering if there's a better way to structure this (not sure if a class is appropriate here).

```
#!/bin/user/python

import os,sys
import argparse  

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input",help="source directory",
        required=True,type=path_check)
    args = parser.parse_args()

def path_check(arg):
    if not os.path.exists(arg):
        print("Directory does not exist. Please provide a valid path")
    else:
        return arg

def main():
    '''
    This main script analyzes the source folder and redirects
    files to the appropriate parsing module
    '''
    parse_args()
    source = path_check() # This is the problem area

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

The error received is

```
TypeError: path_check() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

EDIT:
Here is the corrected code if it's helpful for anyone. I needed to add a description to the argparse argument so I had a means of calling the argument's value, which I could then return.

```
 #!/bin/user/python

import os,sys
import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input",help="source directory",
        dest="input",required=True,type=path_check)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args.input

def path_check(arg):
    if not os.path.exists(arg):
        print("Directory does not exist. Please provide a valid path")
    else:
        return arg

def main():
    '''
    This main script analyzes the source folder and redirects
    files to the appropriate parsing module
    '''
    source = parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: And what don't you understand? You defined it to take an argument, but don't pass any when you call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input",help="source directory",
        required=True,type=path_check)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args     # <====

def main():
    '''
    This main script analyzes the source folder and redirects
    files to the appropriate parsing module
    '''
    args = parse_args()      # <===
    source = path_check(args.input) # <===
```

`parse_args` function has to return the `args` variable to `main`.  And then `main` has to pass its `input` attribute to `path_check`.

`args.input` will be the string that you provided in the command line.

`args` is a simple `argparse.Namespace` object with attributes that correspond to each of arguments that you defined in the `parser`.  Some of those attributes may have a value of `None`, depending on how the defaults are handled.

During debugging it is a good idea to include a

```
print(args)
```

statements, so you see what you get back from the parser.

Answer (score 1):

I usually write the codes separately to keep things easier. I provide my code below for reference.

```
#!/bin/user/python
import os, sys
import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input")    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def path_check(arg):
    if not os.path.exists(arg):
        print("Directory does not exist. Please provide a valid path")
    else:
        return arg

def main():
    '''
    This main script analyzes the source folder and redirects
    files to the appropriate parsing module
    '''
    args = parse_args()
    if not os.path.exists(args.input):
        print("Directory does not exist. Please provide a valid path")
    else:
        source = args.input

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the above stated comment, you need to include argument here

```
source = path_check(argument)
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling a function in main, if you want to pass some variable you need to insert them in the brackets.

```
function(Variable1, Variable2,)
```

and dont forget to put them on the function itself to accept the variable. To return a variable to your main function, simply at the end of the function do a return VariableName as well as adding it in front of the call in main followed by a = sign.

example:

```
main()
   x = 1
   ReturnVariable = function1(x)

function1(x)
   ReturnVariable = x * 2
   return ReturnVariable
```